# html php retain form value

Tags: php, html, forms

As the title says, i'm trying to retain the value submitted from a text form. so I thought the following simple code on the pre-process page would do the trick but the text box is still blank.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="pre_process.php">
        <input name="q" type="text" value="<?php $_GET['q']; ?>" size="80"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you should check it first with if(isset($_GET['q'])) before echoing it to not run in php notices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
<input name="q" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" size="80"/>
```

You need to echo the value out.

To avoid Notices you should use the isset function to check if the value was set

Your code should look like:

```
<input name="q" type="text" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : NULL; ?>" size="80"/>
```

Comment: please complete your answer with `value="<?php echo isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : NULL; ?>"`

I think with this solve all future problem with any servers.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to call [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Your code should read:

`<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>`